How to pass Vec arg and strings args to instruction?
Using anchor
pub fn instruction(ctx: Context<InstructionContext>, arg1: String, arg2: Vec<String>) -> Result<()> { 
How should I "encode" the args to pass them from the client ? Should i pass a String directly, or use Buffer.encode(string) ?
Same question for the Vec arg, how should I pass the array
const ix = await program.methods
                .instruction(Buffer.from(arg1), ["foo", "bar", "foobar"])
                .accounts({
                    ...
                })

(this is not working)

Anchor will automatically serialise the arguments for you.
program.methods
                .instruction("str argument", ["foo", "bar", "foobar"])
                .accounts({
                    ...
                })

Check out the types reference https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/javascript-anchor-types
